# Create current and most recent datetime file - python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to create a log file using python. The specific problem I'm trying to solve is separating datetime into current and previous timestamps based on when the script was executed.

Using below, I want to generate a df that contains two cols (DateTime, Last DateTime), where DateTime returns the `datetime` of when the script is executed and Last DateTime returns the most recent or previous time `datetime` the script was executed.

I want to return these timestamps to a df called `execution_file`.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

times = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Last Datetime', 'DateTime'])

ct = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

def get_current_run_time_stamp(df):

    # try loading the datetime of the last run, else print warning
    try:
        df['DateTime'] = ct
    except:
        # Return current time-stamp if no time exists 
        return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(ct)

execution_file = get_current_run_time_stamp(times)

print(execution_file)
```

expected output:

if script is initially executed at `2000/01/30 14:00:00` and then again 30 minutes later, I'm hoping to df will read:

```
         Last Datetime             Datetime
0                  NaN  2000/01/30 14:00:00
1  2000/01/30 14:00:00  2000/01/30 14:30:00
```

Comment: Don't change the question and invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
        df['DateTime'] = ct
```

You wanted

```
        df['DateTime'] = [ct]
```

---

Also, you want to `return df`, rather than leaving it with an implicit `return None`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to append new times to the df

Comment: You can use pd.concat(). But often you’re better off starting with list of dicts, then keep extending the list, then finally use pd.DataFrame() to create df. Pandas / Numpy are not great at doing repeated allocations, where you keep adding one row at a time. OTOH lists are great at that.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_current_run_time_stamp(df):
    ct = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")# move this part inside the function for this to change during append
    if not df.empty:
        last_datetime = df.iloc[-1]['Datetime']
    else:
        last_datetime = None
    df = df.append({'Last Datetime': last_datetime, 'Datetime': ct}, ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

This will append the row as per the ask and return the dataframe which can be saved later